# Elastic Search Query using should is not working

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I would like to filter my messages containing "No DB record found for Category:" or ""Not all codes match in DB for Category:". But the query returns all the messages that are not containing the above phrase.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {"range": {"timestamp": {"gte": "now-1h/h"}}},
      "should": [
        {"match_phrase": { "message": "No DB record found for Category:"}},
        {"match_phrase": { "message": "Not all codes match in DB for Category:" }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great start, you're just missing `minimum_should_match` (when the query contains a `must` or `filter`, then `minimum_should_match` is 0, so you need to specify it):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {"range": {"timestamp": {"gte": "now-1h/h"}}},
      "minimum_should_match": 1,                                  <---- ADD THIS
      "should": [
        {"match_phrase": { "message": "No DB record found for Category:"}},
        {"match_phrase": { "message": "Not all codes match in DB for Category:" }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Adding "minimum_should_match" worked.

Comment: Hi Val, I have one more question on this. I want these messages to be grouped. Which means I would like  "No DB record found for Category:" messages logged first and then the "Not all codes match in DB for Category:". I tested this with small number of messages and they appear to be grouped which is what i wanted. But i'm wondering if that will work for large number of records.

Comment: Feel free to create a new question since this one is solved

Comment: Sure Val.. I'm creating a new question. Thanks!